# Jboss tools on Eclipse Helios problem

Tags: eclipse-3.6, jboss-tools

I have installed Jboss tools for eclipse helios. but when I try to get priview of a HTml file I get this message:

> Could not open the Visual Page Editor:
>   Bundle
>   org.mozilla.xulrunner.cocoa.macosx is
>   not found.
>
> org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.XulRunnerException:
>   Bundle
>   org.mozilla.xulrunner.cocoa.macosx is
>   not found.    at
>   org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.browser.XulRunnerBrowser.getXulRunnerPath(XulRunnerBrowser.java:226)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.browser.XulRunnerBrowser.(XulRunnerBrowser.java:104)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.editor.XulRunnerEditor.(XulRunnerEditor.java:143)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.mozilla.XulRunnerPreview.(XulRunnerPreview.java:22)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.mozilla.MozillaPreview.createPartControl(MozillaPreview.java:79)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.VpeEditorPart.createPreviewBrowser(VpeEditorPart.java:923)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.jst.jsp.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor.pageChange(JSPMultiPageEditor.java:238)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.jst.jsp.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(JSPMultiPageEditorPart.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2743)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3629)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)

Comment: maybe is this same bug? https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-4523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by installing the 32 bit version of Eclipse Helios.

Use:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR2/eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz

Instead of:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR2/eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz

Comment: Yes, there are no 64 bit xulrunner on osx unfortunately.